# codeigniter redirect not working

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

For some reason I can't spot, redirect in codeigniter is not working. I'm getting the white screen of death.

I set up a "test" controller:

```
class Test extends Controller {
    function Test() {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function index() {
         redirect('home','refresh');

    }
}
```

(I've tried the location and refresh parameters, with no help).

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I've used all this before with good results. Anything else I can check?

Thanks.

John

Comment: A good way to start is to enable all debug and informational messages in `config.php`, set the log threshold to 4, delete today's log file if it exists, and run your script. You may find some valuable info in the log file. Also just to be safe, make sure you can access test/index normally (try echoing something).

Comment: what/where is your `home` controller?

Comment: Madmartigan, I'll try what you suggest.  Thanks!

Comment: Ross, my home controller is the home page for the site.  It works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As it turned out, setting the log threshold to 4 was the answer to figuring this out.  I was able to determine that I was outputting some space, which prevented the redirect from working.  Looking in the logs revealed this.

Thanks everyone for your help, and thanks Madmartigan for suggesting the log setting.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a ? at the end of index.php in your last rewrite rule as such:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]`

If that doesn't work, try changing your `$config['uri_protocol']` (if it's set to `AUTO`) to:

`$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';`